# Ajax Alert Success Message Has Stopped Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, alert

I have code but the alert message is not working. Using Firefox - not sure if that is the problem. Appreciate help please .. new at this.

The code I have:

```
$("#enquiry").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/enquiry/<?php echo $type;?>",
        data:    $("#enquiry_form").serialize() ,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.status == true) {
                //show success message
                alert(data.msg);
                $('#enquiry_form')[0].reset();
                $('.error').html('');
            }else{
                $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
                    console.log(val);
                    $('[id="span_'+ key +'"]').html(val);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have changed various parts of the call and tested enquiry forms but still no alert when button is clicked. The customer enquiry form comes through but because they do not get an alert when they click the button they keep clicking and we receive multiple copies of the same form.

Comment: Late update to above - issue resolved. Found the issue was a typo in table column title. I assume the form was not able to return/resolve full query effecting the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue - there was a typo in the table column title. So I assume the form was not able to resolve the query which effected the alert notification from activating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).